# sibling component communication angular 6

Tags: javascript, components, angular6

I have two sibling components inside a parent component like below

```
<parentComponent>
  <sibling1></sibling1>
  <sibling2></sibling2>
</parentComponent>
```

Am emitting data from sibling 2 to parent. Then am passing it as Input from parent to sibling 1. But as the sibling 1 gets initialized before sibling 2 am unable to get the data on sibling 1. How to get the data on sibling 1 with the same setup.

Comment: One way to do this is, the data can be fetched in parentComponent and you can pass that data to both sibling1 and sibling2. Both the sibling will show loading until the data is available in the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive data in parent component you need run a `callback` function to update `sibling1` data. In order to run a callback in parent you can do something like this.

**SIBLING2**:

```
class Sibling2 {
   @Output() private onChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

   ngOnInit () {
     this.onChange.emit("hello parent")
   }

}
```

**PARENT**:

```
    class Parent {
           private parentData: string = null;

           ngOnInit () {
             this.onChange.emit("hello parent")
           }

           onSibling2Change(data) {
             this.parentData = data; //this will update sibling1 data
           }

        }
```

HTML:

```
<parentComponent>
  <sibling1 [data]="parentData"></sibling1>
  <sibling2 (onChange)="onSibling2Change($event)"></sibling2>
</parentComponent>
```

Comment: Am doing the exact thing what you are doing. Sibling 1 is initialized before Sibling 2. So the data emitted from Sibling 2 is not available in Sibling 1. One way would be to make Sibling 1 load later than Sibling 2. But am not sure how to do this

Comment: Another way you can do is, wrap to setTimeout(() => this.parentData = data, 0);
Let me know if that works.

Comment: I tried setTimeout also. Its not working. Anyway you can check. Thanks

Comment: This is definitely going to work now,

<sibling1 *ngIf="parentData" [data]="parentData"></sibling1>